# create variable name function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript dynamic variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name)

I'm trying to create a function in javascript that has a name dependent on a variable.

For instance:

```
var myFuncName = 'somethingWicked';
function myFuncName(){console.log('wicked');};
somethingWicked(); // consoles 'wicked'
```

I can't seem to figure out a way to do it.... I tried to eval it, but then when I try and use the function at a later time it 'doesnt exist'.. or more exactly I get a ReferenceError that the function is undefined...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a valid use case for this?

Comment: The next question, of course, is "how do I call a function whose name is in a variable?"

Comment: @MikeChristensen, why do you need a valid case for this?

Comment: I don't, I'm just curious.  If you're hard coding in the call, you might as well hardcode in the function definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could assign your functions to an object and reference them like this:

```
var funcs = {};
var myFuncName = 'somethingWicked';
funcs[myFuncName] = function(){console.log('wicked');};
funcs.somethingWicked(); // consoles 'wicked'
```

Alternatively, you could keep them as globals, but you would still have to assign them through the `window` object:

```
var myFuncName = 'somethingWicked';
window[myFuncName] = function(){console.log('wicked');};
somethingWicked(); // consoles 'wicked'
```

Comment: I don't think that this resolves, since `funcs.somethingWicked.name == ""`

Comment: The solution should be this: ```var myFuncName = 'somethingWicked';
var funcs = {
[myFuncName]: function(){console.log('wicked');}
};
funcs.somethingWicked(); // consoles 'wicked'
console.log(funcs.somethingWicked.name); // consoles 'somethingWicked'```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFuncName = 'somethingWicked';
window[myFuncName] = function(){console.log('wicked');};
somethingWicked(); // consoles 'wicked'
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have to create something that depends on a dynamic name for a variable you should be using a property of an object or an array member instead.

```
var myRelatedFunctions = {};
var myFuncName = 'somethingWicked';
myRelatedFunctions[myFuncName] = function (){console.log('wicked');};
myRelatedFunctions['somethingWicked']()
```